# Swift isKindOfClass not work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController and some label and textfield for user to input, and in some point I need to loop over all textfield to collect the user's input.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
   for views in self.view.subviews        {
        if view is UITextField
        {
            println("inside")
        }
        println(views.description)

    }
}
```

For this code, the "inside" never print out. But I do see some the information of views.description

```
   <UILabel: 0x7fa4b1c7bd00; frame = (16 97; 76 21); text = 'FromDate';        opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =           <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa4b1c44580>>
  <UILabel: 0x7fa4b1c9fd60; frame = (16 169; 82 21); text = 'ControlNO'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa4b1c77fb0>>
```

>

```
   <UITextField: 0x7fa4b1c7a050; frame = (106 95; 197 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa4b1c6c800>>

  <UITextField: 0x7fa4b1c9c060; frame = (106 126; 197 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa4b1c9c2c0>>

   <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa4b1d11d20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa4b1d11e00>>
   <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa4b1d253f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa4b1d12f60>>
```

but if I println(views.dynamicType) I could only see ExistentialMetatype.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: A simple typo: You enumerate `for views ...` and then check `if view ..`. That are different variables. – If you change the loop to `for view in ...` then it works as expected. – Voting to close as "off topic because of simply typo".

Comment: myBad! Thanks for point out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop variable is called `views`, but you test `view` (which is
not the loop variable and  therefore identical to `self.view`):

```
for views in self.view.subviews { // "views" here
    if view is UITextField {      // "view" here
        println("inside")
    }
}
```

If you rename the loop variable to `view`

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view is UITextField {
        println("inside")
    }
}
```

then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isKindOfClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:):

```
var tex = UITextField()

if tex.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
    println("yes")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Christian's code will work. Here is another solution.

```
if let view = tex as? UITextField {
    // view is a UITextField
}
```

Comment: is this one any different from "is"?

Comment: I didn't actually know is was a keyword in Swift. I thought you were using that to describe the problem. Looks like I have some more learning to do in Swift haha.